# Failing to open localhost page

Tags: python, django

I try to install django in my mac pro and I finished installing but when I want to run this command :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Stack Feedback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 182, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 204, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I then tried my sqlite3 in the python, it works.
So I wanna how can I do it?

Comment: Did you run manage.py syncdb or similar?

Comment: @frlan seems correct, however, `syncdb` has been deprecated as of 1.7 in favour of `migrate`. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#syncdb

Comment: can you provide your `settings.py` file?

Comment: check your db files permission. or "chmod 777 yourdb.db".
if you use mysql, check your settings of your db connection.

Comment: Thank you everyone ,I have solved the problem by change the path of sqlite3,and It worked!I am really appreciate for your help mua~